# shell script for date between 2 different dates

Tags: bash, shell, date

I'm struggling a bit on how to put the correct date in my shell script for a specific time range. 
For instance i need to check if i'm in the correct range to generate some file based on date(12am - 3am )

so far I'm checking :

```
  workflow_start_time=$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-%d) 23:00:00" +"%s")
  scheduled_run_time=$workflow_start_time

if [ "$(date -d @${scheduled_run_time} +"%H")" -ge 23 ] && [ "$(date -d @${scheduled_run_time} +"%H")" -lt 2 ]; then
```

that is starting at 23 because i need to take into account 1 hour server difference, so this will start around 12 and should finish around 2am, which will be 3am.

any help here?

Comment: can u not convert it to unix time stamp and check ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert date to timestamp.

```
toStamp() { date --date="$1" +%s; }
```

Check if date is between other dates.

```
# [$1, $2): bounds
# $3 current date

isBetween() {
    [[ `toStamp $1` -le `toStamp $3` ]]&&\
    [[ `toStamp $2` -gt `toStamp $3` ]]
}
```

or

```
isTimeStampBetween() {
    [[ $1 -le $3 ]]&&\
    [[ $2 -gt $3 ]]
}
```

if you have timestamps only.

An example to check if a date is between 2 other would be:

```
if $(isBetween 2012 2020 2013) ; then dosomething
```

You can include these functions in your file.

Comment: You're right, but this would be a more generic way to convert. So I rewrite the isBetween function according this special case, where you only use timestamp.

Comment: see the isTimeStampBetween then.

Comment: Explicitly returning `true` or `false` is just silly. If one of the tests fails then the result will be `false` and if they all succeed it will be `true`.

Comment: @tripleee isn't this the expected result?

Comment: I don't understand. If you like `[[ "$a" = "$b" ]] && true` then surely `[[ "$a" = "$b" ]] && true && true && true` is even better?

Comment: You're right. So simply the expressions would be enogh. I see now. Clear.